# Setting up local environment with Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Python. Trying to work get this [Google Cloud Python tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql). I'm stuck at the part where it say "Installing dependencies" where do I run this `virtualenv -p python3 env` and other code?

Tried running them in the Google Cloud SDK Shell inside that particular folder that just says it's "not a recognized command"

Just having difficulty setting this local environment, can someone help?

Comment: You can install virtualenv from these instructions ... https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: Use Cloud Shell if you haven't a linux environment, it's easier at the beginning. Windows is sometime tricky, and if you are beginner, it's an additional difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

At some point it was a command in the tutorial :

```
 git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python.git
```

cd to the directory that contains the requirements.txt file:
and then run (assuming you have installed virtualevn in your machine):

```
virtualenv -p python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial you are referring to](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) is one part of deploying a complex Python app. With an assumption that you already completed the setup instructions.

> This page is part of a multipage tutorial. To start from the beginning
>   and read the setup instructions, go to [Python Bookshelf app](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/tutorial-app).

You will need to go through the setup instructions before starting. Again it assumes that, you have Python development environment set up. If not please follow [Setting Up a Python Development Environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup)